# How to delete my Facebook notes?

Tags: facebook

I really want to delete all my Facebook notes, but when I go to

```
https://www.facebook.com/[ME]?sk=notes
```

I see 2.806 notes at the top but the screen is blank.

In what way can I delete all my notes?

[image: screenshot]